Why aren't the :first-child and :last-child pseudo selectors grabbing the divs?
When I use nth-child() and last-of-type it works fine. Also, I keep getting different displays with vscode live-server and on jsfiddle.


div:first-child {
  background-color: darksalmon;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

div:last-child {
  background-color: black;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
<div>
  <h1>Hex to Binary</h1>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Insert your hexidecimal value" />
  <input type="Button" value="Convert" />
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Binary to Hex</h1>
</div>




Is there a reason you keep removing the code snippet which demonstrates the problem?

For some reason the html is displaying different on here than on live-server. I'm not sure why.

In its current state, the question appears to be nothing more than a typo.  The <style> element is outside the document.  It should be within the <head> or <body> instead.

Does style not work if it's not in the head element?

It's certainly unusual to keep it outside of even the <html> element.  That might work, though I wouldn't be surprised if behavior could change between browsers.  More to the point... The question states that the styling currently doesn't work, so are you asking whether this code doesn't work in some way or are you telling us that this code isn't working in some way?  The question seems to keep changing...

Yeah, sorry. I'm trying to say it's not working in the way I intended. On VSCode, the first div was selected just fine and had it's background color applied, but the second one wasn't being selected. I wanted to know why. Sorry for the confusion.

@Jerry - The :last-child doesn't work because the second div isn't the last child of its parent. The <style> element gets moved by the HTML parser into the body element, so it, not the second div is the last child of the body element.

Woah I never knew that. So many weird quirks about the language I still don't know. Thanks for the help.

I inspected the html for my page and I see that live server injected some hidden divs of it's own. I'm guessing other sites and the code snippets on here maybe put some hidden elements themselves. That's probably why it was displaying different. I learned something new today. I'll try to rely more on ids and classes in the future.

As stated in this W3 Schools article, the <style> tag must go inside the <head> section of the document.
This would be a more correct way of doing this:
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hex-Binary Convert</title>
    <style>
      div:first-child {
        background-color: darksalmon;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
      }
      div:last-child {
        background-color: blue;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>Hex to Binary</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Insert your hexidecimal value"/>
      <input type="Button" value="Convert"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Binary to Hex</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

I changed the background color to blue to make it easier to see.
